# How to loop until == true

Tags: c++, loops

So I'm making a Tic Tac Toe  game but I got stuck in the point where if position is already taken => get the user to enter another position. Here is what  I'm talking about:

```
int pos[3][3]=
{
  {0,0,0},
  {0,0,0},
  {0,0,0}
};
bool CheckForPos(int x,int y)
{
    if (pos[y][x] == 0) return true;
   return false;
}
```

This is the matrix where I check if position is already entered.
 And the code in **int main ()** :

```
if( CheckForPos(y,x) )
{
  pos[y][x] = 1;
  chess[y][x] = 'X';
}
else
{
    while (pos[y][x] = 1)
    {
      cout << "Spot already taken." << endl;
      cin>>get;
    }
}
```

Where  is my mistake and how could I fix it ? Any ideas ?

Comment: You are using only one equals in the while loop, which will always return true as it is just assigning the value

Comment: It's better to provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Apart from the said ==/= issue. You're code repeats the loop as long as pos[x][y] is equal to one. And you simply read in a new value. But as far as I can see you do not update x/y therefore once you enter the loop you should be stack there.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but there is a lot of obfuscating verbiage in `CheckForPos`.  What's wrong with just `return pos[y][x] == 0;`?

Comment: @JamesKanze Well I'm still a beginner and a friend of mine explained the bool that way. But i might use that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this....

```
 if( CheckForPos(y,x))
{
  pos[y][x] = 1;
  chess[y][x] = 'X';
  //take one count variable for counting that how much position has be finished like if
    count value is greater than your array size than terminate it
  count++;
}
else
{
    //simply print your message and again get your position
    cout << "Spot already taken." << endl;
    cin>>get;

}
```

Comment: I tried this first but it didn't worked for me. However it works now after  fixed some errors. Thank you.

Comment: I think you may some other error because count variable for checking you slop how much slot remaining

Answer (score 4):

Use `==` instead of `=`
Former is comparison, latter an assignment

Comment: I can´t believe that. You may have other errors, but == will definitely help with this problem

Comment: As far as I can see, the value of pos[y][x] is not altered in your while-loop. Once its value is 1 you have an endless loop.

Comment: @tgmath Yes I saw that  when i tested. I gives me the option to enter about 3-4 times per player.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (pos[y][x] = 1)
{
    cout << "Spot already taken." << endl;
    cin>>get;
}
```

the same as

```
while (pos[y][x] == 1)  // == instead of = !
{
    cout << "Spot already taken." << endl;
    cin>>get;
}
```

is infinity loop because while statement always returns true